# How to run formatjs compile?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

How to run formatjs compile command without replacement of already translated messages?
Now I run it this way:

```
../../node_modules/.bin/formatjs compile lang/ru.json --out-file compiled-lang/ru.json
```

Comment: What do you mean by `without replacement of already translated messages`?

Comment: @LongHo In this file "compiled-lang/ru.json" I have already translated messages (initial). When I run previous command I get new file with new pairs of key + value, which all values are in default language, but the expected result is mix of my initial messages and new messages from "lang/ru.json"

Comment: you're supposed to update `lang/ru.json` with your translation. `compile` only turns string into ASTs

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom formatter with your own compile function:
https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/cli/#custom-formatters

This is what my formatter file looks like:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const originTranslations = require(argv['out-file']);

module.exports = {
  compile: function (msgs) {
    const results = {};
    for (const k in msgs) {
      const defaultMessage = msgs[k].defaultMessage;
      if (originTranslations[k]) {
        results[k] = originTranslations[k];
      } else if (defaultMessage) {
        results[k] = defaultMessage;
      } else {
        results[k] = 'MISSING TRANSLATION';
      }
    }
    return results;
  },
};
```

You need to pass in this formatter with `--format` option

```
yarn formatjs compile lang/ru.json --out-file compiled-lang/ru.json --format <your formatter file>
```